# How To Use Backreference in Grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep, text-processing

I have a regular expression with a backreference. How can use it in a bash script?

Such as I want to print what matches to (.*)

```
grep -E "CONSTRAINT \`(.*)\` FOREIGN KEY" temp.txt
```

If apply it to

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_dm` FOREIGN KEY
```

I want to output

```
fk_dm
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$ echo 'CONSTRAINT `helloworld` FOREIGN KEY' | grep -oP '(?<=CONSTRAINT `).*(?=` FOREIGN KEY)'
helloworld
```

---

```
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

---

```
(?=pattern)
    is a positive look-ahead assertion
(?!pattern)
    is a negative look-ahead assertion
(?<=pattern)
    is a positive look-behind assertion
(?<!pattern)
    is a negative look-behind assertion
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on ?<= and ?=

Comment: What if I want to print multiple matches, can I do this?

Comment: Your should use `substitution`.

Comment: Actually I noticed that this returns all instances.

Comment: great example. have to resurrect this if you don't mind.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -E 'CONSTRAINT \`(.*)\` FOREIGN KEY' temp.txt
```

Comment: You repeated part of the OP's question, changing only the quotes which have no effect in this case.

Comment: They do: The OP asked "How can use it in a bash script?" and the single quotes are the answer.

Comment: The backticks are escaped in the original so they aren't seen as command substitution.